# Unable to request click.manage or click.send scopes in Docusign click API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to authenticate a call to Docusign's Click API using the Node SDK. I'm importing the ApiClient through the docusign-click as `import { ApiClient } from 'docusign-click';`.

My API setup looks like this:

```
this.apiClient = new ApiClient({
      basePath: this.configService.get('DOCUSIGN_CLICKWRAP_BASE_PATH'),
      oAuthBasePath: '',
    });
```

and I'm requesting a JWT like this:

```
const response = await this.apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
        this.configService.get('DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATOR_KEY'),
        this.configService.get('DOCUSIGN_USER_ID'),
        ['click.manage'],
        Buffer.from(
          this.configService
            .get<string>('DOCUSIGN_PRIVATE_KEY')
            .replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
        ),
        30,
      );
```

When I try to request a JWT this way, I get `Error: Bad Request`. However, when I replace `['click.manage']` with `['signature']` the JWT is generated, so I know the rest of the call is fine.

Is there something else I need to do to allow me to request a click API scope and call to the click API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your consent request should also include **click.manage** and **click.send**. These are two separate things.
To get consent you need to build a URL that looks like this:

[https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?redirect_uri=[Redirect](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?redirect_uri=%5BRedirect) URL in IK]&scope=click.manage%20click.send&client_id=[YOUR IK]&response_type=code

And simply go to this URL in the browser.

Then make the request for JWT again and it should work.